How to stop running node in the output of vsCode so i can run javascript code that doesn't use node.js
I am trying to run the code of my script.js tab in a project I'm making.
Because previously I installed node.js, now all my js files run with the node output, which does not let me use dom elements.
This is the error code:
c:\Users\Nicolás\Desktop\Gatoprojecto\script.js:2
const gatoCajas=document.getElementById("gatoContainer");
            ^

 ReferenceError: document is not defined
 at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Nicolás\Desktop\Gatoprojecto\script.js:2:17)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
 at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
 at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
 at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
 at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.13.0

This is not the problem of course, I know node can't run dom elements, I just want to stop using node in the output.
I looked up how to do this but I could not find someone solving this, or maybe I didn't look well enough.

What extension or command are you using to run the code? It doesn't do so naturally, so there's something extra there.

Im just pressing the run button at the top right.

Ah, I forgot they have that as I've never used it. Lol. For me, under View -> Run, there's a Settings button next to Launch Program that allows changing the current config, and a dropdown to add a new config for the runner. The file that stores configs (and a lot of other user settings) is at C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json.

if you run JS on the command line you NEED NodeJS, if you need document and HTML nodes you NEED to run in a browser

If you want to run JavaScript code that interacts with the DOM you need to run it on the client-side and as Node.js does not have access to the DOM since it typically runs on the server-side.
To resolve this issue, run your JavaScript code in a browser environment where the DOM is available, you need to create an HTML file that includes your JavaScript file.
Here's a simple example of how you can structure your files:

Create an HTML file (e.g., index.html) in the same directory as your JavaScript file (script.js).

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Project</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Include your JavaScript file -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Update your JavaScript file (script.js) to interact with the DOM within the browser environment:

// script.js

// Wrap your code in a function to ensure it runs after the DOM has loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const gatoCajas = document.getElementById("gatoContainer");
  // Your code that interacts with the DOM here
});

By creating an HTML file that includes your JavaScript file and running the HTML file in a browser, your JavaScript code will execute in the browser environment where the DOM is available.

It still throws ReferenceError: document is not defined.

you sure, you're running html file and not file via node ?
